# How to select the child element of 'this'?

Tags: jquery

Im trying to do a basic drop down menu.How do i change the font color of the link Parent item on mouse hover?

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Parent 01</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Parent 02 > </a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item 01</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 02</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 03</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Parent 03 > </a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 04</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 05</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 06</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 07</a></li>
    </ul>           
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Parent 04</a></li>
</ul>



$('#nav li').hover(
    function () {
        $('ul', this).slideDown("slow");

    }, 
    function () {
        $('ul', this).fadeOut("slow");          
    }
);
```

I tried `$('a', this).css("color", "blue")`; but it changes the color of every `a`. I just need to change the color of the `a` of the parent menu item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these two to your functions:

```
$(this).addClass("hover-item");
```

and

```
$(this).removeClass("hover-item");
```

It's better that you use CSS classes so you define styles in your CSS and not set inline styles which is most of the time a bad practice.

But be aware that this will add the class to your `LI` element not `A` directly. This will make it even more flexible since you can change `LI` content to your liking and keep functionality as is. And adjust CSS accordingly.

In your case CSS should look like:

```
li.hover-item > a
{
    color: #f00; /* adjust colour to your liking */
}
```

which would only set colour on child links and not all descendants (which would change colour of all links in submenus as well).

### Use CSS only

Do you realise you can easily use CSS only solution for what you'd like to achieve? Sliding and fading of your menus will still be done as they are now, but you can set `A` highlighting in your CSS file:

```
#nav li
{
    padding: 0;
    ...
}

#nav li a
{
    padding: 3px 5px;
    display: block;
    ...
}

#nav li a:hover
{
    color: #f00; /* adjust colour to your liking */
    ...
}
```

If your `LI` has padding I suggest you remove it and add padding to `A` that's inside it (as in my CSS). Also set `display: block;` for it to occupy the whole available space of the `LI`.

It's always better to use CSS-only solution than JavaScript if possible.

Comment: wat was i thinking!! yes i could use just CSS,thanks  a lot mate

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse the Dom with

```
$(this).parent()
```

and

```
$(this).children("li")
```

With the children you can select the specific elements such as "li" or "li:first" etc

In your case I would use a class with the style and then:

```
$(this).parent().addClass("HoverClass");
```

and:

```
$(this).parent().removeClass("HoverClass");
```